# Angular ng-pattern regex validation using scope data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I'm pretty new at Angular, so forgive me if I'm asking or looking at this the wrong way, but I'm trying to dynamically build a form from fields in a database. When the page loads, I'm pulling data from the database and assigning those values to the scope in the Controller. In the HTML, I'm looping through those scope values to populate the page. In this example, `fields.field.dataType.type="text"`, `{{fields.field.isRequired}}="true"`, and `{{fields.field.regEx}}="/^\d{11}$/"`.

```
<div ng-if="fields.field.dataType.type=='text'" class="form-group control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && fieldsForm.$invalid]">
  <div ng-repeat="fields in selectedPage.fieldValue">
    <ng-form name="fieldsForm>
       /*other code*/
       <div class="controls"
         <input type="{{fields.field.dataType.type}}"
              ng-model="fields.value"
              name="{{fields.field.fieldName}}"
              ng-required="{{fields.field.isRequired}}"
              ng-pattern="{{fields.field.regEx}}" />
       </div>
      <span class="help-label" ng-show="submitted && fieldsForm.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid field</span>
       /*rest of code*/
    </ng-form>
  </div>
```

The other parameters within the input tag work perfectly, but the regex field always returns invalid. I can substitute `ng-pattern="{{fields.field.regEx}}"` with `ng-pattern="/^\d{11}$/"` and the validation works as expected.

Is there something different I have to do to pull in this regular expression from `{{fields.field.regEx}}`? Why would the validation work when I hard-code `"/^\d{11}$/"` in `ng-pattern` but fail when it's pulling from `{{fields.field.regEx}}` even though they contain the same data?

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: remove `{{` and `}}` from all attributes of the input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NgPattern` expect it's value to be a `Regex` parseable expression.

According to [angularjs ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) docs:

> - If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used    directly.
> - If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in `^` and `$` characters. For
>     instance, `"abc"` will be converted to new `RegExp('^abc$')`.

In your case, the regex is being parsed like a string, so the problem is with the scaping of the back slash inside the string `"/^\d{11}$/"`. So, to fix it, you mustn't surround your regex with `/`, because it's not a regex, it's a string with the pattern for a regex, and you must escape your regex pattern as well (if it isn't being scaped yet), like so: `"^\\d{11}$"`.

Also, you don't need to use `{{}}` since your regex string comes from an object on scope you can use it like this: `ng-pattern="fields.field.regEx"`.

Comment: This is something I saw, but the regEx is dependent on the specific field. I thought about making a function in Controller

Comment: Whoops, clicked enter by accident. I tried creating a in controller: $scope.getRegexValue=function(field) {var pattern = new RegExp("/^\d{11}$/"); return pattern; } and in HTML, ng-pattern=getRegexValue(field), but get lots of errors: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question, actually the problem is with scaping chars inside a string. Updated my answer

Comment: Don't the /'s need to be at the beginning and end of the string? If I change the scope variable to "^\\d{11}$" and use ng-pattern="{{fields.field.regEx}}", I get the following error: Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^\\d{11}$].         Thanks for helping so far, I feel like it's close :)

Comment: Yes you don't need, because it is comming from the server like a string, then `ngPattern` will evaluate the expression like `new Regex(expression)` as I said. Also your problem is caused because you are rendering the string, try to change `ng-pattern` to: ng-pattern="fields.field.regEx"`

Comment: I think that was it! It works when I have "^\d{11}$" in the database and use ng-pattern="fields.field.regEx". Thanks for your help!